# Why/How Apks are modifiable?

Tags: android, ios, apk

I've been familiar with the idea since a long time that Apks are easily modifiable. Doing a simple google search shows tons of resources to do it personally or there are handful of websites that provides modified Apks already.

So what are we exactly talking about here! The fact that anyone can easily download a modified version of SnapChat that would no longer send the notification when the person screenshots the story. Or the fact that Pro version of Spotify can be downloaded with a single click giving access to full library of Spotify. Or the fact that any game available has a modified Apks version that would give unlimited coins or whatever virtual currency is used. This seems to me a very alarming situation but for reasons has been the same since years and no one talk about it(and seriously no one talk about it, doing a google search only points out to link telling how to modify Apks easily).

I just don't get why this has been the same for so many year. Every year there is a yet another version of android with "minor" UI improvements, but this problem is not addressed at all.

One last thing I would like to call out is that, on the other side of spectrum there are platforms like IOS and Windows, where this doesn't seems to be a problem. The way Windows 10 packing system works is similar to android, an Appx can be distributed from or without the Microsoft Store, but there are no modified Appx available or atleast one I know of!

Comment: Code is just code. No matter what it runs on, it **will always be modifiable**.

Comment: Yeah and don't you think it is a really big issue! There are ways out of it, like IOS does. But good ol android!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Or the fact that any game available has a modified Apks version that would give unlimited coins or whatever virtual currency is used"* - that is why you track in game currency (and all important data for that matter) on the server.

*"Or the fact that Pro version of Spotify can be downloaded with a single click giving access to full library of Spotify*" - proper way of handling this is to associate the "Pro" with the account and only grant access to some features to those accounts having the "Pro" flag. Once again this is handled on the server. Even a modified client cannot access "Pro" features if the server blocks access.

iOS has modified ipa files as well. The "problem" is that if they are modified they are no longer signed and cannot be installed as easily - only with a jailbroken device where you skip the signing verification.

---

*"This seems to me a very alarming situation"* - no. The client can **never** be trusted, you always have to write proper server code for anything that you *really* want to validate. Same way you dont do the password verification in javascript on the client but on the server.

Comment: Okay! So just wondering why modified Apks don't get unsigned as well in android(so not allowing for installation without rooting)?

Comment: And even if some of the problems are solved by moving files to a server, still it won't fix the issue. What about simple utilities app that provide Pro feature? Those Pro feature can be unlocked without paying. It is a big issue that no one care about! How do you plan on fixing issues like SnapChat hack using server based model?

Comment: @JaiSharma That's why validating crucial purchases on a server is important. This is exactly what this answer is about.

Comment: @JaiSharma *"simple utilities app that provide Pro feature"* - you cannot ever protect them. Your app / code is with the client now and the client has full control over its execution. *"It is a big issue that no one care about"* - no. Firstly it is faaaar from a "big issue", do you have *any* numbers to back up your claim? Secondly some people care about it, the thing is that it simply is impossible to prevent it.

Comment: @JaiSharma they may loose their original signing but there is nothing stopping you from simply re-signing the new apk and letting someone install it - you can just install APKs from everywhere, without rooting. That is not the case for iOS.

Comment: @luk2302 So I guess you're telling it is totally fine for modified apks to exist, and no action can/needs to be taken.

Comment: @luk2302 "client now and the client has full control over its execution". True but it's not as if user has the raw code available, the execution takes place on the android and there should be measures to secure it.